# FluentAssertions Defaults for type

Tags: fluent-assertions

I'm testing complicated object graphs with FluentAssertions and I want to set defaults for `ShouldBeEquivalentTo`. The problem is that the object graph re-used the same base-type for a lot of the properties. I just want to set up my `AssertionOptions`s once per Type but I can't seem to find out how.

Example: I have this object graph:

```
public class Inner
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
}

public class Outer : Inner
{
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }
}
```

I set up a [Custom Extension](https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/#building-your-own-extensions):

```
public AndConstraint<InnerAssertions<T>> BeEquivalentTo(T expectation)
{
    return base.BeEquivalentTo(expectation,
        c => c
            .RespectingRuntimeTypes()
            .Excluding(r => r.Two));
        }
```

Now I want this test to pass:

```
new Outer
{
    One = "1",
    Two = "2",
    Inner = new Inner {One = "inner.1", Two = "inner.2"}
}.Should()
    .BeEquivalentTo(new Outer
        {
            One = "1",
            Two = "3",
            Inner =new Inner {One = "inner.1", Two = "inner.3"}
        });
```

This obviously fails on `root.Inner.Two`, but I hope this makes clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using an `IMemberSelectionRule` to exclude `Inner.Two` from equivalency comparisons

```cs
class ExcludeTwo : IMemberSelectionRule
{
    public bool IncludesMembers => false;

    public IEnumerable<IMember> SelectMembers(INode currentNode, IEnumerable<IMember> selectedMembers, MemberSelectionContext context) =>
        selectedMembers.Where(e => !(e.DeclaringType == typeof(Inner) && e.Name == nameof(Inner.Two)));
}
```

and then add it to the stat [`AssertionOptions`](https://fluentassertions.com/tips/#using-global-assertionoptions) with e.g. a `ModuleInitializer`.

```cs
[ModuleInitializer]
public static void SetDefaults()
{
    AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing(e => e.Using(new ExcludeTwo()));
}
```

Comment: I'll take a look at that, but i'm afraid my actual case is a bit more convoluted...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid this situation is to pass an anonymous type to `BeEquivalentTo` that only includes the properties that you care about in those specific tests.